# SQL: Pivot + Group by in one go

Tags: oracle

[image]

I wish to pivot INFO2 into 2 columns.
INFO3 data should adjusted accordingly after the PIVOT.

The challenge is I also have a date column, which I want to take the MAX of.
The MAX(Date) should also be grouped by (lot_no, mcid).

Is there a way of doing this in one fell swoop?
Without resorting to temporary tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that without using `PIVOT`. Your data:

```
with data as
(
  select 1 as lot_no, 1 as mcid, 1 as info2, 111 as info3, date'2015-01-01' as dat from dual union all
  select 1, 1, 2, 222, date'2015-01-02' from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 1, 333, date'2015-01-03' from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 2, 444, date'2015-01-04' from dual  
)
select * from data;

    LOT_NO       MCID      INFO2      INFO3 DAT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
         1          1          1        111 2015-01-01 00:00:00
         1          1          2        222 2015-01-02 00:00:00
         2          2          1        333 2015-01-03 00:00:00
         2          2          2        444 2015-01-04 00:00:00
```

Now the result:

```
with data as
(
  select 1 as lot_no, 1 as mcid, 1 as info2, 111 as info3, date'2015-01-01' as dat from dual union all
  select 1, 1, 2, 222, date'2015-01-02' from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 1, 333, date'2015-01-03' from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 2, 444, date'2015-01-04' from dual  
)
select
  lot_no,
  mcid,
  max(decode(info2, 1, info3, null)) as info21,
  max(decode(info2, 2, info3, null)) as info22,
  max(dat)
from
  data
group by
  lot_no,
  mcid
;

    LOT_NO       MCID     INFO21     INFO22 MAX(DAT)
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
         1          1        111        222 2015-01-02 00:00:00
         2          2        333        444 2015-01-04 00:00:00
```

This is simply a `GROUP BY` and picking the need value for `INFO21` and `INFO22` by transforming unneeded values into `NULL`, then keeping the needed value with `MAX` (because we need to use an aggregate function here).

---

(Section below added by question originator)

While trying to understand the above answer, I found it useful to study the query below as an intermediate step.

```
with data as
(
  select 1 as lot_no, 1 as mcid, 1 as info2, 111 as info3, date'2015-01-01' as dat from dual union all
  select 1, 1 , 2, 222, date'2015-01-02' from dual union all
  select 2, 2 , 1, 333, date'2015-01-03' from dual union all
  select 2, 2 , 2, 444, date'2015-01-04' from dual 
)
select
  lot_no,
  mcid,
  decode(info2, 1, info3, null) as info21,
  decode(info2, 2, info3, null) as info22,
  --max(dat)
  dat
from
  data
;
```

This gives,

```
LOT_NO  MCID    INFO21  INFO22  DAT
1   1   111     1 Jan 15
1   1       222 2 Jan 15
2   2   333     3 Jan 15
2   2       444 4 Jan 15
```

[image]

This is before the "group-by" used in the answer above.

It's also useful that null values are automatically excluded, by ORACLE aggregate functions like MAX. Makes it easy to ignore them when merging rows.

Comment: awesome, my original idea is very complicated, involving joins and temporary tables.